# wrap every odd word in span tag jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to be able to wrap every odd word in span tag but exclude the first word, I found some code online where the code wrapped the second word in a span tag at https://codepen.io/ShadyThemes/pen/OpNGjr but then found another example that wrapped the first, third and fifth word in a span tag at http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/buNYU/ which is ok but would like to exclude the first word

Below is what I currently have

```
var words = $('h5.introsubtitle').text().split(' ');
   var numWords = words.length;
      for (i=0; i<numWords; i++) {
         if (i%2 == 0) {
            words[i] = '<span>' + words[i] + '</span>';
         }
       }

      $('h5.introsubtitle').html(words.join(' '));
```

What I currently have is below

```
<h5 class="introsubtitle"><span>COMPUTER</span> REPAIR <span>FAST</span> AND <span>SECURE</span>
```

What I am trying to achieve is the following

```
<h5 class="introsubtitle">COMPUTER REPAIR <span>FAST</span> AND <span>SECURE</span></h5>
```

Comment: You can simply add that condition in your word wrapping condition. Like so:`if (i%2 == 0 && i > 0) { ` or you could shift your starting index to 1

Comment: You can start your loop with 1 or check for 1 in your condition.

Comment: I just thought of that way as well @JavidAskerov so instead of starting the loop with 0, I could start it from 1. I amended the line for (i=0; i<numWords; i++) { to for (i=1; i<numWords; i++) { and that worked as well

Comment: It should be `for (i=1; i<=numWords; i++) { ... }` otherwise you are missing the last word.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
.class:nth-child(odd) {
...
}
```

Comment: He want to split on words, not elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the SPANs for styling I would recommend to wrap each word in a span and do the styling in CSS (as was also stated in another answer).

```js
var words = $('h5.introsubtitle').text().split(' ');
var numWords = words.length;
for (i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
  words[i] = '<span>' + words[i] + '</span>';
}

$('h5.introsubtitle').html(words.join(' '));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

h5.introsubtitle span:nth-child(odd) {
  color: blue;
}

h5.introsubtitle span,
h5.introsubtitle span:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="introsubtitle">COMPUTER REPAIR FAST AND SECURE
</h5>
```